# How to solve the ng serve Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace

Tags: .net, angular, recaptcha

I'm trying to run `ng serve` but I am getting

> Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.
> I have tried opening integrated terminal on VS code, but didn't work.

Does anyone has any idea on how to fix `ng serve` error

> Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

The whole idea behind is to add reCAPTCHA in web page built with angular and .NET, any suggestion on that is also appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

In case nx is installed in your project, try replacing 'ng' with 'nx'.
e.g ng serve --> nx serve

Answer (score 4):

It probably means that you are positioned inside of a wrong directory.

You should be positioned inside of directory where package.json is located.

Use: cd {path_to_your_angular_project}

Comment: @Dovor, thanks for the answer, but I tried from every possible directory, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

For me "angular.json" was missing from my project root. Copying it into the root from a different branch solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For mac, go to the file where you have angular.json and right click, then select "open in integrated terminal". On the terminal, type in "ng serve" then  click (enter/return key).It should work.